# C# - Define a dictionary of generic functions

Tags: c#, generics, functional-programming

How do i define a dictionary that maps a Type to a function that takes this type as input

Something like:

```
var stringifiers = new Dictionary<Type, Func<T, string>> {
        { typeof(string), s => s},
        { typeof(float), f => f.ToString()},
        { typeof(bool), b => b.ToString()},
    };
```

usage :

```
stringifiers[bar.getType()](bar)
```

The dictionary definition above does not compile obviously

> The type on namespace 'T' counld not be found

Comment: The is no way to do that with generics, it is like saying that you want a `List<T>` where you can add different types to a single instance (string, float, bool). In your case your function parameter will have to be an `object`.

Comment: There is no need for this dictionary at all. If every method is going to call `ToString` then just call `ToString` (and yes, you can do that on a `string`). No need for a `Dictionary`.

Comment: yes, well its only for the example to work, in reality i will have some other logic in there

Comment: Please show us a [mcve] of the real logic.

Comment: @IPValverde - Of course you can do this with generics.

Comment: Do you know the type (that you are going to use to access the dictionary) at compile time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this class:

```
public class Stringifier
{
    private Dictionary<Type, Delegate> _store
        = new Dictionary<Type, Delegate>();

    public void Store<T>(Func<T, string> value)
    {
        _store[typeof(T)] = value;
    }

    public Func<T, string> Fetch<T>()
    {
        return (Func<T, string>)_store[typeof(T)];
    }

    public string Fetch<T>(T value)
    {
        return this.Fetch<T>().Invoke(value);
    }

    public string Fetch(Type type, object value)
    {
        return (string)
        (
            typeof(Stringifier)
                .GetMethods()
                .Where(x => x.Name == "Fetch")
                .Where(x => x.IsGenericMethod)
                .Where(x => x.ReturnType == typeof(string))
                .Select(x => x.MakeGenericMethod(type))
                .First()
                .Invoke(this, new [] { value })
        );
    }       
}
```

Then you can do this:

```
var stringifier = new Stringifier();

stringifier.Store<string>(s => $"!{s}!");
stringifier.Store<float>(f => f.ToString());
stringifier.Store<bool>(b => b.ToString());

var bar = "XXX";

var value = stringifier.Fetch(bar.GetType(), bar);

Console.WriteLine(value);
```

The output I get is `!XXX!`.

Comment: while I understand what i asked for is impossible, this implementation is probably the closest to the usage i wanted, very nice !

Comment: Great solution! I would only change the name of the method Fetch to Stringify.

Answer (score 2):

If you're not stuck on the dictionary and you want a one to one relationship between the type and the function, you can use generic static variables to store and retrieve the functions and gain type safety in the process.

The "magic" occurs in `StringInternal<T>`.  Because `StringInternal<string>.Stringify` is a different variable from `StringInternal<float>.Stringify`, you can store a Func in that static variable and access it using the type.

The `Stringifier` class is a non-generic class with generic functions so that we can use type inference, simplifying our calling syntax.

```
public static class Stringifier
{
    public static void Set<T>(Func<T, string> func)
    {
        StringifierInternal<T>.Stringify = func;
    }

    public static string Stringify<T>(T value)
    {
        return StringifierInternal<T>.Stringify(value);
    }

    private static class StringifierInternal<T>
    {
        public static Func<T, string> Stringify { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
Stringifier.Set<string>(v => v + "stringified");
Stringifier.Set<float>(v => v.ToString() + "floatstringified");
Stringifier.Set<bool>(v => v ? "it's twoo" : "not twoo");

Console.WriteLine(Stringifier.Stringify("X"));
Console.WriteLine(Stringifier.Stringify((float)17));
Console.WriteLine(Stringifier.Stringify(true));
```

Output:

```
Xstringified
17floatstringified
it's twoo
```

Comment: Grax, your implementation is very neat, but i went with a solution that does not involve global variables

Comment: Understood. Globals represent a commitment that isn't always desirable.

Answer (score -1):

Another way using a delegate:

```
public class Stringifier
{
    public string StringifyObject<T>(T input)
    {
        return input.ToString();
    }
}

public class Stringify
{
    public delegate string Callback<T>(T input);
}
```

Then usage:

```
var stringifier = new Stringifier();
Stringify.Callback<string> stringCallback = stringifier.StringifyObject;
Stringify.Callback<bool> boolCallback = stringifier.StringifyObject;
Stringify.Callback<float> floatCallback = stringifier.StringifyObject;

var stringifiers = new Dictionary<Type, dynamic>();
stringifiers.Add(typeof(string), stringCallback);
stringifiers.Add(typeof(bool), boolCallback);
stringifiers.Add(typeof(float), floatCallback);

string dog = "dog";
bool truth = true;
float fourPointFive = (float)4.5;

Console.WriteLine(stringifiers[dog.GetType()](dog));
Console.WriteLine(stringifiers[truth.GetType()](truth));
Console.WriteLine(stringifiers[fourPointFive.GetType()](fourPointFive));
```

Maybe this is useful to someone, as I was trying to do something similar to what OP wanted, but where reflection wasn't an option.